# Ansible. When for exact string only

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Launching next command I can get all installed schemas:

```
# fusiondirectory-insert-schema -l
core
cosine
nis
inetorgperson
core-fd
core-fd-conf
ldapns
template-fd
openssh-lpk
```

If some schema is missed I can install it by command:

```
# fusiondirectory-insert-schema -i mail-fd-conf.schema
```

So in Ansible using `shell` module I can get all installed schemas into variable:

```
- name: Get info which schemas are enabled
  shell: fusiondirectory-insert-schema -l
  register: fusiondirectory_schemas
```

And then analyze this output and install skipped schema:

```
- name: Apply mail schemas for Fusiondirectory
  shell: fusiondirectory-insert-schema -i mail-fd-conf.schema
  when: ('mail-fd-conf' not in fusiondirectory_schemas.stdout)
  args:
    chdir: "/etc/ldap/schema/fusiondirectory/"
```

Let's suppose I wish to install few different schemas and use only one `fusiondirectory_schemas.stdout` output for `when`. So my question is how to use in `when` argument regex like `^mail-fd-conf$` (but no `mail-fd-conf-something` or `test-mail-fd-conf`) because I want only exact overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [match filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings).**

```
- name: set regex pattern
  set_fact:
    regex_pattern: "^.*mail-fd-conf.*$"

- name: Apply mail schemas for Fusiondirectory
  shell: fusiondirectory-insert-schema -i mail-fd-conf.schema
  when: fusiondirectory_schemas.stdout |match("{{ regex_pattern }}")
  args:
    chdir: "/etc/ldap/schema/fusiondirectory/
```

Comment: Looks awesome. Thanks!

Comment: But unfortunately it produces  warning  `[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: not (fusiondirectory_schemas.stdout | match("{{regex_pattern}}"))`

Comment: @ipeacocks i don't see the warning  here in my env. could you please change that to `not (fusiondirectory_schemas.stdout | match(regex_pattern))`, remove the `{{ }}` works good in my env.